# how to versioning file or folder name in React.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using Create React app and Apache. And I have a cache busting problem.
When every time I change my code and deploy server, build it, chrome doesn't get new code but old one.
So I searched about it, and got found that problem caused by the cache busting.
I saw the following code as a solution.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="theme.css?version=20190416">
```

It was to write version after the file name.
But I do not know how to apply the above method to react.

This is my react code.

App.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import './App.css';
import {Route, Switch} from "react-router-dom";
import Homefrom "./page/Home";
import About from "./page/About";

class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        return (
             <Switch>
                 <Route exact path="/home" component={Home}/>
                 <Route exact path="/about" component={About}/>
             </Switch>
        );
    }
}

export default withRouter(App);
```

Root.js

```
const Root = () => {
return (
    <Router history={history}>
        <Route path="/" component={App}/>
    </Router>
);
};

export default Root;
```

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import 'core-js';
import 'react-app-polyfill/ie11';
import './index.css';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
import Root from "./Root";

ReactDOM.render(<Root/>, document.getElementById('root'));

serviceWorker.unregister();
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
    <meta
      name="viewport"
      content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no"
    />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />

    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />
    <title>React.js</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I've also reading about how to set up output file in webpack.config.js file, but I do not get it.
Someone's help me please.
Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is because you need to hash your bundles so that your browser will bust the cache once it sees that the hash has changed. In your webpack configuration you will need to set your output property like this:

```
output: {
   filename: "[name].[hash].js",
   chunkFilename: "[name].[hash].js"
```

},

Where the `filename` is the bundle you generate from React and the `chunkFilename` is the small code of code webpack splits into different files to make it more performant. On the Apache side, you will need to make sure that you are busting the cache whenever you find get a different filename, but that is set by default I think.

Comment: Thanks for your comment!! There is one question. When I look in the node_modules/react-scripts/config folder, I have only the webpack.config.dev.js file and not the webpack.config.js file. Can I modify the webpack.config.dev.js file like that?

Comment: yep, as long as the create react app injects your bundle and is not using a direct naming convention. If it fails, it's because react is used to a absolute name like `main.bundle.js`. If so, you could use https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin . By then, I'd advise you to eject your app and write your own index.html file

Comment: I really thanks for your comment. And I ejected the project and modified webpack.config.prod.js as you told me. But do I need webpack-dev-server to build it? I do not know how to check the webpack.config.prod.js is applied to my project. :(

Comment: Happy to help you if you publish it to github and give me a link to the repo